# String or binary data would be truncated when using it in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I create this `TYPE` table in database:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[AccessLevel] AS TABLE
(
      [RoleId] [INT] NULL,
      [Access] [NVARCHAR](1) NULL,
      [IsDelete] [BIT] NULL
)
GO
```

and I need to insert data into it but when I use this code:

```
DECLARE @AccessLevel AccessLevel 

INSERT INTO @AccessLevel VALUES (4, 'dfdfg', 0)
INSERT INTO @AccessLevel VALUES (4, 'dfdfg', 0)

EXEC InsertAndUpdateAccessLevel @AccessLevel
```

and this is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertAndUpdateAccessLevel]
    (@AccessLevel AS AccessLevel READONLY)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO RoleAccess (RoleId, Access, IsDelete)
        SELECT * FROM @AccessLevel
END
```

I get this error:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 4, Line 5
>   String or binary data would be truncated

What's the problem? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You're trying to `INSERT` the value `'dfdfg'` in an `[nvarchar](1)`. That is clearly more than 1 character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to insert **5 length character('dfdfg')** into your 1 length column `[Access] [nvarchar](1)`.

Increase the value of your column in `Table type`.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[AccessLevel] AS TABLE(
  [RoleId] [int] NULL,
  [Access] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
  [IsDelete] [bit] NULL
 )
GO
```