# Must declare the scalar variable "@AccessLevel". in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write a stored procedure for this: I pass the table value parameters to this stored procedure, first I need to check data `Access` and `RoleId` exist in the database; if not, I insert it into table.

I wrote this :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertAndUpdateAccessLevel]
    (@AccessLevel AS AccessLevel READONLY)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @AC AccessLevel;
    SET @AC = @AccessLevel;

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT Id
                   FROM RoleAccess 
                   WHERE RoleAccess.RoleId = @AC.RoleId
                     AND RoleAccess.Access = @AC.Access)
        INSERT INTO RoleAccess (RoleId, Access, IsDelete)
            SELECT * FROM @AccessLevel
END
```

but I get these errors:

> Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Procedure InsertAndUpdateAccessLevel, Line 8 [Batch Start Line 7]
> Must declare the scalar variable "@AccessLevel".
>
> Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Procedure InsertAndUpdateAccessLevel, Line 8 [Batch Start Line 7]
> Must declare the scalar variable "@AC".
>
> Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Procedure InsertAndUpdateAccessLevel, Line 15 [Batch Start Line 7]
> Must declare the scalar variable "@AC".
>
> Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Procedure InsertAndUpdateAccessLevel, Line 16 [Batch Start Line 7]
> Must declare the scalar variable "@AC".

What's the problem? How can I solve it?

**Edit**

```
  CREATE TYPE [dbo].[AccessLevel] AS TABLE
  (
        [RoleId] [INT] NULL,
        [Access] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
        [IsDelete] [BIT] NULL
  )
```

Comment: Can you include the AccessLevel type definition?

Comment: You're trying to use a TableVariable like a Scalar Variable. The types are completely different. A Table Variable acts like table, you don't `SET` it's value, you perform DDL operations (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, etc) statement against it. `SET @AC=@AccessLevel;` makes no sense; how do you `SET` a table to be another table? It would be like running the statement `SET dbo.MyTable = dbo.YourTable;`

Comment: @EzLo i update the question

Comment: The objects being referenced here are identical to those in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59102047/string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-when-using-it-in-a-stored-procedure), but from a completely different account? If you're using a second account to get around a question ban, this is very much frowned upon. It is referencing objects the exact same name and definitions, so far too much of a coincidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below changes -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertAndUpdateAccessLevel]
(
 @AccessLevel AccessLevel READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            Id
        FROM RoleAccess 
        WHERE exists (select 1 from @AccessLevel as x where 
              RoleAccess.RoleId=x.RoleId
              AND RoleAccess.Access=x.Access)
    )
    INSERT INTO  RoleAccess (RoleId, Access, IsDelete )
    SELECT * FROM @AccessLevel
END
```

Comment: This will insert all rows from the table variable, **including the ones that already exist on the destination table**, as long as there is at least one that doesn't.

Comment: . .  and it does not *update* anything, only inserts, so the procedure name is perfectly misleading.

Answer (score 1):

`@AccessLevel` is a table variable, so you will have to treat it as one, and also avoid using `*`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertAndUpdateAccessLevel]
    @AccessLevel AS AccessLevel READONLY
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO RoleAccess (
        RoleID,
        Access,
        IsDelete)
    SELECT
        A.RoleID,
        A.Access,
        A.IsDelete
    FROM
        @AccessLevel AS A
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 
                'RoleAccess does not exist currently'
            FROM
                RoleAccess AS R
            WHERE
                R.RoleID = A.RoleID AND
                R.Access = A.Access)

END
```

Answer (score 1):

> first I need to check data Access and RoleId exist in the database; if not, I insert it into table.

This is the wrong approach.  You should let the database do the checking, using a unique constraint or index.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_roleaccess_roleid_accessid on roleaccess(roleid, accessid);
```

Voila!  You will now have data integrity.  You can then use a `TRY`/`CATCH` block for your stored procedure:

```
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY

        INSERT INTO RoleAccess (RoleId, Access, IsDelete)
            SELECT al.RoleId, al.Access, al.IsDelete
            FROM @AccessLevel al
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                              FROM RoleAccess ra
                              WHERE ra.RoleId = al.RoleId AND ra.Access = al.Access
                             );
    END TRY;
    BEGIN CATCH
    -- do something here if there is a duplicate
    END CATCH;
END;
```

It is quite important to let the database validate the data when it can.  In particular, this prevents race conditions -- where two different threads run the stored procedure at the same time.

Perhaps more importantly, this validates *data integrity* regardless of how the data is changed.  The unique constraint/index ensures no duplicates even when some clueless person goes into the database and manually alters data.